# How to set auto height for textarea on screen load in angular

Tags: textarea, height, auto

In my angular 8 application, I want to set a dynamic height to the text area when the screen loads.
I don't want to display a scrollbar either vertically or horixzontally.
I see many javascripts ways of doing by setting scrollheight. Is there a way we can do in angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Yes you can do that like below:
    On component.html:

   <textarea [ngClass]="getCSSClasses()"></textarea> 

   On component.ts
   ngOnit(){
   getCSSClasses() {
    let cssClasses;     
        cssClasses = {
            'height': 100px,
            'width': 200px,
        }
        return cssClasses;
     }
}
```